# How to add new column with specific header name and content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table and a button that allow user to add a new column. Right now user able to add new column when pressing "add", however i wish the header of the added column can be named as `Group1` and `Group2`, `Group3`.. for the other press attempt.

Currently it only showed the number of the rows and columns:

[image]

Expected Output (When user click `add column` 3 times, the header should become `Group1` and so on):

[image]

```js
// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('member_table'), // table reference
    i;
  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
    txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

Comment: You must not use "createCell" since it is deprecated, Instead use createElement and put "table", "tbody", "th", "td" to create the table. It would be best to split this action in separate functions that do each of these and you can call them with any data you want to pass in.

Comment: @КольоПеев, what's deprecated? That's a custom function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a line to update the value after the column is built. Note that I have made some best-practice improvements to variable names and initialization (type, location).

Also, you should refactor a bit so that the first cell in the column is a `th`.

```js
let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
    txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* width: 100%; */
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply , it worked perfectly. But this method doesnt work if user can delete column right? For example, a user add group `group1` and `group2` after that he delete `group2`.  The next time he press add group again, it will show `group3` instead of `group2`

Comment: Correct, but that's a different question. You'd need more robust application state handling at that point.